# Порядок валидации полей serializer ( DRF )

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, сериализация

Если кратко, у меня есть сериализатор наследуемый от миксина для неких задач, который наследуется от `rest_framework.serializers.Serializer`.

У этого миксина есть 1 поле, валидация, которого требует значение определённого ключа из контекста сериализатора, но этот ключ как и его значение появляется там после валидации другого поля из дочернего сериализатора.

Суть: Как я могу поменять порядок валидации полей, что-бы поле "2" валидировалось перед полем "1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Выкрутился другим путем, избавившись от зависимости в порядке, хотя на самом деле выглядит теперь не так элегантно, но это другое.

В целом, решение можно найти, если покапаться и понять как работает функция `is_valid()`, если я конечно не ошибаюсь в том, какая функция является зачинщиком валидации.